# Fractions as entries in a matrix - can I give the entries a bit more space?

Tags: spacing, matrices

...say in a 2x2 matrix, the fractions are almost touching each other and is sort of hard to read, especially fractions involving a lot of greek letters.

One such matrix in my code is this:

```
$$\setlength{\delimitershortfall}{0pt} \mathcal{A} =
\begin{bmatrix}
1-\frac{1-\sigma_2}{2} & \frac{1-\sigma_2}{2} \\
\frac{1-\sigma_2}{2} & 1-\frac{1-\sigma_2}{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
```

Comment: There are quite a few ways to create a matrix. Please tell us the way(s) you use at the moment. Please also tell us if the matrix occurs in display-mode math or text-mode math.

Comment: Hi @Mico, please see my edited question - thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the case of a 2x2 matrix, it's probably easiest to achieve your objective by adding a spacer directive such as `[1ex]` after the first line-break instruction.

Incidentally, the use of `$$` to initiate and terminate display-math mode in LaTeX is heavily deprecated. See [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001) for a longer discussion of this issue.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'bmatrix' environment and '\text' macro
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
1-\frac{1-\sigma_2}{2} &   \frac{1-\sigma_2}{2} \\
  \frac{1-\sigma_2}{2} & 1-\frac{1-\sigma_2}{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\quad\text{versus}\quad
\begin{bmatrix}
1-\frac{1-\sigma_2}{2} &   \frac{1-\sigma_2}{2} \\[1ex]  % <-- observe "[1ex]" spacer
  \frac{1-\sigma_2}{2} & 1-\frac{1-\sigma_2}{2}
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```